# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.EventEmitter()')

Tags: react-native, eventemitter

I'm trying to use EventEmitter in react-native, but it's giving following error.

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'react-native';
.
.
.
const events = useRef(new EventEmitter()).current;
```

**Why doesn't it work?**

[image]